# How do I use new Lomography 120 Film in a vintage Diana F Flash Camera?

Tags: film, medium-format, vintage, lomo

I'm relatively new to film photography and have just recently returned to it after a few years of inactivity.

I got a vintage point-and-shoot Diana F (the totally plastic one) and it takes 120 film. I was also gifted Lomography 120 film and it loaded fine but the modern film does not have numbers for my little red window that tells me what frame I'm on. It does have the phrase "DON'T THINK" upside down which appears as you roll — which I find rather ironic. Does anyone have a general rule of them for how many turns I should do for a full frame or should I abandon hope of using this film and buy a more clear cut and probably cheaper brand?

Answer (score 2):

"DON'T THINK" has 11 characters corresponding to [eleven 6cm x 6cm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120_film#Frame_sizes) shots expected from 120 film.

Answer (score 0):

Number of turns will vary. As the takeup spool gets film on it, one turn will have a larger radius and circumference, pulling more film across. You will need numbers.

Comment: if you are sure there are no numbers on their film i would contact them from the their contact page of there web site.  There is no mention of their film not having numbers on their site. it does mention that  medium format film should have numbers and they should be upside down in the window. I own their reproduction of this camera but i have not used their brand of film.